# I'm trying to solve this python problem but here this error occurs. How to solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Question: Given an array of integer nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target.

```
def twoSum():
    n = input("")
    t = tuple(n)
    nums = t.split(',')
    target = int(input(""))
    i = target - nums[0]
    for j in nums:
        if i == j:
            print([k, j])    
twoSum()`
```

**error**

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' nums = t.split(',') Line 4 in twoSum (Solution.py) twoSum() Line 10 in <module> (Solution.py)`

Comment: Why are you calling `tuple()`?  What is the purpose?

Comment: I think you can avoid worrying about input and printing stuff, the description asks for neither. Hardcode some example list and target and call your function with that. At which point you can probably start over from scratch.

Comment: BTW - it's an interesting question, but you have to understand the problem thoroughly before try it. Hint - search S/O.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is in the format: "1,2,3" you can split the input string directly and not convert it to a number like this:

```
n = input("input: ")
string_array = n.split(",")
int_array=list(map(to_int, string_array))

def to_int(string):
  return int(string)
```

Now you have an list of numbers.
To solve the problem further you could do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(int_array)):
  for j in range(len(int_array)):
    if (not(i==j) and int_array[i]+int_array[j]==target):
      return i,j
```

Here target is the number you want to be the sum.
Of course there are other solutions that are more efficient at solving this problem but this one works (hopefully) and is simple.